# How to use the BottomNavigationController with SideNavigationController

Tags: cosmicmind

I would like to use the SideNavigationController (SlideOutBar) with a BottomNavigationController (BottomNavigationController)

My usecase is similar to the "App" in the examples, "Recipes". When tapping on "Recipes" there is a table with tabs at the bottom. My use case I would like "Recipes A", "Recipes B", "Recipes C" etc... on the sidebar in which updates the main view with different combinations of tabs or a view with no tabbar.

I'm a bit confused how switch out these combinations from the SideBarNavigation. In my app delegate I have:

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainViewController") as! MainViewController
    let sideViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sideViewController") as! SideViewController
    let scratchPadViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scratchPadViewController") as! ScratchPadViewController


    bottomNavigationController.viewControllers = [mainViewController, scratchPadViewController]
    bottomNavigationController.selectedIndex = 0
    bottomNavigationController.tabBar.tintColor = MaterialColor.teal.base
    bottomNavigationController.tabBar.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.grey.darken4


    // Configure the window with the SideNavigationController as the root view controller
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = SideNavigationController(rootViewController: bottomNavigationController, leftViewController: sideViewController)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

In my SideBar case 0 a new combination of tabs,case 1 with be just one controller and no tabs, case 3 original set of tabs, etc... How do I transition with clicking the item on the sidebar? Do I create a new bottomNavigationController and then set that? do I update the existing one?

```
           switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            //NEW COMBINATION OF TABS
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainViewController") as! MainViewController
            let blueViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("blueViewController") as! BlueViewController

            getAppDelegate().bottomNavigationController.setViewControllers([mainViewController, blueViewController], animated: true)
            //remove scan button
            mainViewController.hasScanButton = false
            mainViewController.hasTabbar = true

            //sideNavigationController?.closeLeftView()
            //sideNavigationController?.transitionFromRootViewController(getAppDelegate().bottomNavigationController)
            //sideNavigationController?.transitionFromRootViewController(getAppDelegate().bottomNavigationController,
                                                                       duration: 1,
                                                                       options: .TransitionNone,
                                                                       animations: nil,
                                                                       completion: { [weak self] _ in
                                                                        self?.sideNavigationController?.closeLeftView()
                })
        case 1:
            //place terminal
            let mainViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainViewController") as! MainViewController

            //remove scan button
            mainViewController.hasScanButton = false
            mainViewController.hasTabbar = false



            sideNavigationController?.transitionFromRootViewController(mainViewController,
                                                                       duration: 1,
                                                                       options: .TransitionNone,
                                                                       animations: nil,
                                                                       completion: { [weak self] _ in
                                                                        self?.sideNavigationController?.closeLeftView()})
        default:
            break
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: I started writing an answer to this and realized it is a wonderful article/blog post. I will write that up and link to this answer. Shouldn't take long.

Comment: thanks looking forward to it.